# Blazor issue with generic Tuple-parameter

Tags: c#, generics, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a simple component, which is extending a third-party dropdown-component. It's called this way in MyLanguagePicker.razor

```
<MyDropDown TValue="string" Data="@Languages" OnChange="@OnSelectedAsync"  />

@code{
    private IEnumerable<(string, string)> Languages => _configuration.GetSection(Constants.Configuration.Keys.Cultures).GetChildren().Select(c => (c.Value, c.Key));
}
```

The component itself (MyDropDown.razor)

```
@inherits MyComponentBase<MyDropDown<TValue>>

@typeparam TValue

<RadzenDropDown TValue="TValue" Data="@Data" TextProperty="Text" ValueProperty="Value" />

@code{      
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<(TValue Value, string Text)> Data { get; set; }
}
```

However, when building this I get an error in the generated `cs`-file

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'stringValue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(string, string)>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(stringValue, string Text)>'

This is the part which throws the error in `MyLanguagePicker.razor.g.cs` which is the component the `MyDropDown` is used by.

```
public partial class MyLanguagePicker : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
{
    #pragma warning disable 1998
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    {
        __builder.OpenComponent<My.WebSite.Shared.RazorComponents.MyDropDown<string>>(0); // error on the end                                               ###########   
        __builder.AddAttribute(1, "Data", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(stringValue, System.String Text)>>(
```

As you can see, it somehow is missing a whitespace, as it should be `string Value` instead of `stringValue`. The `Value` is the generic part of `MyDropDown`. If I change `Data` to `IEnumerable<(string Value, string Text)` the build runs without any error.
If I add the missing whitespace it also runs without any errors.

**Update to answer first comments**

I already tried renaming it to TDropDownVal and changing the name to `Whatever` instead of `Value` as it might be an issue having the tuple-value as `TValue Value`. But `TDropDownVal Whatever` is still throwing the same error on build.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Razor SDK to me - does it do the same if you change the name of TValue to something else random like Foo?

Comment: I would also see what happens if you move the `@code` section to a .cs file

Comment: @MisterMagoo tried both. Same error

Comment: I'd recommend filing an issue on the githubs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error goes away when you change this in your `MyDropDown.razor`. This then shows that the `RadzenDropDown` does not know how to deal with a tuple at runtime. It appears to to want to convert it to a string.

```
[Parameter]
public IEnumerable<(string , TValue )> Data { get; set; }
```

The Razden Component does not know how to convert this to a string for display. I dont know anything about Razden components but you maybe able to manage this if it allows you to render your own content.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not helping. Using `typeof` will generate `__builder.AddAttribute(1, "Data", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(System.String Text, typeof(string)Value)>>`

Comment: @KingKerosin You sure? It removed the error when i checked it.

Comment: Yes. I am totally sure. Just created a project from scratch (using Blazor Server) and still got the same error no matter if I use `string` or `@typeof(string)`. How have you tested this?

Comment: I've added the project to [github](https://github.com/kuebelkasten/TupleTest.git) if you want to give it a try.

Comment: @KingKerosin It appears the Razden component wants to convert the value to string and doesnt know how to with a tuple. I removed the names off the Tuple values and it passed it to the Razden component.

Comment: Removing the names and creating an override to be passed to the 3rd-party component did the trick